# Newbie needs help to insert item into QlistWidget

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I created two pushbuttons (InsertItem and RemoveLast item) for a QlistWidget, which should be used to display a list of 3 items(Chair, Table, Mirror ). I need help writing the codes to insert these items sequentially, and also remove them.

My codes:

```
----mainwindow.h---

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>

class QListWidget;

namespace Ui {
     class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
      Q_OBJECT

public:
         explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void insertItem();
    void removeItem();

private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };

#endif 




---mainwindow.cpp---

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(insertItem()));
connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(removeItem()));

 }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::insertItem()
{


}

void MainWindow::removeItem()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should get you going:

```
void MainWindow::insertItem()
{
    QListWidgetItem *newItem = new QListWidgetItem( ui->listWidget );
    // Do stuff with your new item
}

void MainWindow::removeItem()
{
    if( ui->listWidget->currentItem() )
        delete ui->listWidget->currentItem();
}
```

To delete the last item:

```
delete ui->listWidget->item( ui->listWidget->count() - 1 );
```

See also [QListWidget::selectedItems()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the last added item. I want to be able to delete the last item without having to select it